# PowerShell Script to catch Adobe Reader Errors upon opening PDFs

Tags: powershell, pdf

I've written a PowerShell script to open all PDF files within a folder and its subfolders. I know that some PDFs will open with an Adobe Acrobat Reader DC error.

The goal of the script is to open all pdf files within a directory (and subdirectories), and log the file path of any that open with an error (nothing should be logged for files that open successfully).

I believe this is because PowerShell is successfully opening the file without errors on its side; the error is happening on Adobe's side. The error that Adobe Acrobat Reader DC is showing is:

```
Adobe Acrobat Reader DC could not open 'FileName' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).
```

Is it possible to capture these Adobe Acrobat Reader DC errors using PowerShell? My current scrip is below:

```
$TargetPath = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test.pdf"
$ErrorLog = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\ErrorLog.txt"

Try
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetPath *.pdf -Recurse | ForEach { Invoke-Item -Path $_.FullName }
}
Catch
{
    "Error Opening $_.FullName" | Add-Content $ErrorLog
}
```

Please Note that I am a complete beginner at PowerShell and I've written this script based off of what I've gathered from my Google searches. Any tips to improve it are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is really vital you spend time getting up to speed on it, in order to avoid, misconception, error, bad habits, etc...

[Getting started with Powershell](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/using_powershell/f/general-12/68263/getting-started-with-powershell)

[Windows PowerShell Survival Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/183.windows-powershell-survival-guide.aspx)

Error handling is very specific, to the type of error you are trying to catch or even if you should. Try/catch only catches terminating errors. There error you are getting is not a Adobe app terminating error, Adobe opened, but just a file open error.

[PowerShell Tutorial – Try Catch Finally and error handling in PowerShell](https://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell)

[Understanding Non-Terminating Errors in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/)

> One way to force the error to stop Windows PowerShell, instead of
>   permitting it to continue to the next line, is to change the
>   ErrorAction preference from Continue to Stop. I can do this at the
>   cmdlet level. I use the –ErrorAction automatic parameter from the
>   Get-ChildItem cmdlet (Dir is an alias), and I change it to Stop. This
>   causes the error to terminate the Windows PowerShell execution and
>   forces it to the Catch block. Here is the change:

```
Try {dir c:\missingFolder -ErrorAction Stop}
Catch [System.Exception] {"Caught the exception"}
Finally {$error.Clear() ; "errors cleared"}
```

***Update for OP***

As for ...

> Anyway, what I can't figure out based on your comment and the links,
>   is whether this type of "file open error" is something that can even
>   be picked up as a Non-terminating error at any point using PowerShell.

... If you are trying to trap the file error, you can't because it never opened, only the app assigned did. Adobe will load the bad file name in its list, even though the open attempt failed. So, you also cannot use Invoke-Item for this either. You have to use the called app/process name. In this case, AcroRd32.

The below will work, but you will note it will never write the file name in the log the way you have it, but it will write the message. If you use the default $Error variable, you'll get more. Also, always avoid using names that are reserved or very close to the reserved variables in PowerShell. Hence the reason I pointed you to the additional training.

You also have several things in your post that are not logical. 
You pass in a single file name, but yet, do a dir search for all pdfs files. Why? that would never work anyway, because of the explicit single file request. So, that ForEach is not needed at all, neither is the Get-ChildItem. Yet, remember the app parent, Adobe in this case will always start and load and will require human interaction on the fail to open.

So, you end up here:

```
$TargetPath = 'D:\Documents\B1UD8+QD0gS.pdf'
$TargetPath = 'E:\temp\TestBadPDF.pdf'
$ErrorLog = 'E:\temp\ErrorLog.txt'

Get-content -Path $ErrorLog

# What is in the log now

$Error.Clear()
# My new log


# Start the file 
Invoke-Item -Path $TargetPath

# Get the process title
$ProcessHandle = (Get-Process -Name AcroRd32).MainWindowTitle

# Parse the file name
$FileName = (($TargetPath) -split '\\')[-1]

#  Validate the process call
If ($ProcessHandle -eq "$($FileName) - Adobe Acrobat Reader DC")
{
    # Custom success message
    Add-Content -Path $ErrorLog -Value "Success Opening $TargetPath"  
}
Else
{
    # Custom error message
    Add-Content -Path $ErrorLog -Value "Error Opening $TargetPath"    
}

# Check the log
Get-content -Path $ErrorLog
# My new log

Success Opening D:\Documents\B1UD8+QD0gS.pdf

# repeat the process using a bad file

$TargetPath = 'E:\temp\TestBadPDF.pdf'
$ErrorLog = 'E:\temp\ErrorLog.txt'

Get-content -Path $ErrorLog
# My new log

Success Opening D:\Documents\B1UD8+QD0gS.pdf

 $Error.Clear()

 Invoke-Item -Path $TargetPath
$ProcessHandle = (Get-Process -Name AcroRd32).MainWindowTitle
$FileName = (($TargetPath) -split '\\')[-1]

 If ($ProcessHandle -eq "$($FileName) - Adobe Acrobat Reader DC")
{
    # Custom success message
    Add-Content -Path $ErrorLog -Value "Success Opening $TargetPath"  
}
Else
{
    # Custom error message
    Add-Content -Path $ErrorLog -Value "Error Opening $TargetPath"    
}

 Get-content -Path $ErrorLog
# My new log

Success Opening D:\Documents\B1UD8+QD0gS.pdf
Error Opening E:\temp\TestBadPDF.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for the links and advice, postanote. I do understand that if I want to become more advanced at PowerShell, I'll need to commit more time to it than I have so far. I have already reviewed some links (such as the 3rd one you sent) before posting this, but most of them operate on an assumption of some knowledge of PowerShell which makes it difficult to find a starting point. Anyway, what I can't figure out based on your comment and the links, is whether this type of "file open error" is something that can even be picked up as a Non-terminating error at any point using PowerShell.

Comment: See my update for you and as you can see. Knowing what should be used, what should be in place, parse and compare as needed, is not something obvious to a beginner. Logic is paramount to your course of action.

Comment: I'll comment on each paragraph due to character limitations: "... If you are trying to trap the file error, you can't because it never opened, only the app assigned did. Adobe will load the bad file name in its list, even though the open attempt failed. So, you also cannot use Invoke-Item for this either. You have to use the called app/process name. In this case, AcroRd32." I am trying to get the file path or file name of all files which open with an error. I've updated my post to reflect the goal of my script.

Comment: "The below will work, but you will note it will never write the file name in the log the way you have it, but it will write the message. If you use the default $Error variable, you'll get more. Also, always avoid using names that are reserved or very close to the reserved variables in PowerShell. Hence the reason I pointed you to the additional training." I assume you're referring to $Error/$ErrorLog. I'll keep that in mind. The additional training you linked was filled with a rabbit hole of links which makes it very difficult to find a starting point, but I'll search for other options.

Comment: "You also have several things in your post that are not logical. You pass in a single file name, but yet, do a dir search for all pdfs files. Why? that would never work anyway, because of the explicit single file request. So, that ForEach is not needed at all, neither is the Get-ChildItem. Yet, remember the app parent, Adobe in this case will always start and load and will require human interaction on the fail to open." In my actual script, I pass in a folder instead of a specific file name. Sorry for the confusion. I'm looking to search in that folder and all of its subfolders.

Comment: "So, you end up here:" I appreciate your time with this script. I'm taking a look to see if I can apply it in a way that works for my needs. I'll update once I work with it. Thanks.

Comment: As for this... (I pass in a folder instead of a specific file name. Sorry for the confusion. I'm looking to search in that folder and all of its subfolders.), so you are literally opening multiple files in Adobe, and you are trying to trap which on fails. That's not really going to work the way you think, as you'd be trying to open Adobe of every file call. You really need to rethink this one and the goals for it.

Comment: The goals for it aren't up for debate though. The goal is to find which files display that error message so that I know which files are corrupt. I'm certain that I'm not going about it the correct way to accomplish that, which is why I'm on here trying to provide as much info as I can to get productive feedback to look in the right direction.